# Service Fabric project fail to add reference to Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, service-fabric-on-premises

I am working on a project which is using Service Fabric for microservices. I quite new to ServiceFabric and my first assignment is to use ApplicationInsight to collect telemetry data from the Service Fabric application. So I was supposed to use the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native package, since it would be possible to capture SF context data with telemetry. I am also referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet documentation.

As a initial step, I created a sample stateless SF project with a default template and configured Application Insight. Then I tried to install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native package per the documentation. But I got the below error:

```
Install-Package : NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 BasicCalculatorService -> Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 3.2.162 -> Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal (= 3.2.162) 
 BasicCalculatorService -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.0.467 -> Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal (= 
3.0.467).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native -V ...
```

It seems like Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal is not updated on the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native package to work with SF.

How can I proceed with this? Should I to download the NuGet package separately and reference the assembly manually?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, there is a explicit note that says:

> You may need to install the
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnistics.Internal package in a similar
>   fashion if not preinstalled before installing the Application Insights
>   package

That means, they know about this problem, but will let to you discover it. :)

**`Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnistics.Internal`** is an implicity dependency on 
*`Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services`*, because both are implicit and target different versions, you have to explicitly declare which one you to use for both.

In this case, you should add the package `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal 3.2.162` before you install the package `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native`

Just keep in mind, because they target different versions, you might face issues on runtime, the ideal would be having both on same version.